# When launching gazebo no GUI overlay apears, and 'undefined symbol' error is printed in terminal

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.  I followed GUI overlay tutorial "Display Simulation Time". When launching Gazebo no GUI overlay appears, and following error is printed in the terminal:

[Err] [Plugin.hh:180] Failed to load plugin /.../ libgui_example_time_widget.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5QTest18lastMouseTimestampE
[Err] [RenderWidget.cc:311] Unable to create gui overlay plugin with filename[libgui_example_time_widget.so]

The other tutorial "Spawn spheres" results in similar error

I am using
Gazebo 9.0.0
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Qt version 5.9.5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19734/when-launching-gazebo-no-gui-overlay-apears,-and-%27undefined-symbol%27-error-is-printed-in-terminal/) by [arturs](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5636/arturs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-12-04**:
This is a known issue on Gazebo 9 + 18.04: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2541/gui-plugins-failed-to-load

**Comment by [deb0ch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/17426/deb0ch/) on 2020-05-13**:
This issue is apparently not publicly visible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I installed Ubuntu  16.04 LTS, and now this problem is gone, GUI overlays works as expected.

Now there is this weird behavior in model editor, when resizing shapes (In previous setup with ubuntu 18.04 it worked just fine ), but since i don't need to use model editor, it's not a problem.

---

Originally posted by [arturs](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5636/arturs/) with karma: 11 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0